# What is causing invalid operation on my draw arrays call?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Using WebGL I am trying to draw a simple triangle from scratch.

I have experience writing openGL applications in C++, and have looked at the webGL reference card to translate my code.

However, I am having difficulty debugging the application.
The particular error message I am getting is:

> GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

The entire code is here: https://github.com/gheshu/webGL_experiments

The vertex data is laid out as 3 vectors of 3 floats.
Three attributes exist: position, normal, and color, and should be bound on indices 0, 1, 2.

some important snippets:

mesh class:

```
class Mesh{
    constructor(){
        this.num_vertices = 0;  
        this.vbo = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*3*3, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*3*3, 4*3);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(2);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(2, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*3*3, 4*3*2);
    }
    upload(buffer){
        console.log(buffer);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        this.num_vertices = buffer.length / 9;
    }
    draw(){
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.num_vertices);
    }
    destroy(){
        gl.deleteBuffer(this.vbo);
    }
}
```

program class:

```
class GLProgram{
    constructor(vertShader, fragShader){
        this.prog = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(this.prog, vertShader.id);
        gl.attachShader(this.prog, fragShader.id);
        gl.bindAttribLocation(this.prog, 0, "position");
        gl.bindAttribLocation(this.prog, 1, "normal");
        gl.bindAttribLocation(this.prog, 2, "color");
        gl.linkProgram(this.prog);
        var log = gl.getProgramInfoLog(this.prog);
        if(log.length){
            console.log();
        }
        gl.detachShader(this.prog, vertShader.id);
        vertShader.destroy();
        gl.detachShader(this.prog, fragShader.id);
        fragShader.destroy();
    }
    bind(){
        gl.useProgram(this.prog);
    }
    destroy(){
        gl.deleteProgram(this.prog);
    }
}
```

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 position; 
attribute vec3 normal; 
attribute vec3 color; 

varying vec3 vColor;

void main(){    
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);  
    vColor = color; 
}
```

fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;    

varying vec3 vColor;    

void main(){    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);   
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or tips you may have in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of your draw.js file, you destroy `mesh` and `prog`:

```
mesh.destroy();
prog.destroy();
```

In JavaScript `window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);` will actually invoke `onFrame` after those `destroy` methods are called. So by the time `onFrame` is executed both `mesh` and `prog` don't exist. I would recommend reading more about [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) so you can destroy these later (i.e. after your animation loop has stopped running).

You can verify the behavior just by removing those `destroy` lines and it will render fine.

Comment: This was the solution. I could've sworn I had tried removing those two lines. I will definitely look into more of the details behind that function and js's asynchronous nature in general. Thank you very much. Here's the triangle: http://i.imgur.com/GVOHe2x.png